# Fixing projection in DWG for ArcGIS Pro

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, autocad

I am working on a map of campus for work. The services in charge of technical services gave me a .DWG which contains 1194 layers from various construction projects over the year. The study area is in France.

When I try loading it into ArcGIS Pro 2.9, some elements appear in Sweden, others in Norway, some far away from the world map, and others at the 0;0 point in the Atlantic. Several elements do not even display when I zoom to them.

I have tried to define the projection to Lambert 93 (EPSG 2154) of the original file. The original sketch is in centimeters. I have georeferenced it in AutoCAD before exporting it again. Neither of the methods worked.

**How can I make sure my CAD file appears where it is supposed to appear in ArcGIS Pro?**

I am fluent in ArcGIS Pro, and I do have access to AutoCAD, but absolutely no experience.

EDIT: I converted the drawing units to meters using the INSUNITS command in AutoCAD. And managed to reduce the number of layers to a more reasonable number. I georeferenced the drawing in AutoCAD again.
I imported the drawing again in ArcGIS. This time, using the CAD to geodatabase tool. The drawing is visible as polylines. But it is still the wrong size and position.

Comment: If your dwg is in centimeter the first step is to convert it to meters as EPSG 2154 will expect meters

Comment: I couldn't find where to convert units in AutoCAD. I tried changing it, but only changed the interpretation of the values. AutoCAD does ask for the units while georeferencing. So I was hoping this would be enough.

Comment: Please post the drawing. That sounds like the culprit.